# Oracle - Clone table - Structure, data constraints and all

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I know I can copy a tale structure and data by

```
create table testtable1 as select * from sourcetable
```

Is there any way to actually clone everything, triggers, constraints, grants etc?

Thanks in advance. We are running 10G.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look into `dbms_metadata`, especially its procedure `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function (see this [tahiti link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#BGBBIEGA)).

So, in your case, you would first do a

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'SOURCETABLE') from dual;
```

As per *be here now*'s comment: dont forget the `dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl`:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('TABLE', 'SOURCETABLE') from dual;
```

And then work from the given output.